# VBA legend and plot area resizing

Tags: excel, vba, charts, resize, legend

I have an Excel chart which changes on selections made in slicers.
I noticed that the plot area and the legend area change depending on the made selection.

I tried to fix the position and size for the plot area using vba, but this simply does not work unfortunately.

The plot area and the legend keep on resizing, causing the legend overlapping the plot area. Which I obviously do not want.

I have this code, placed in the worksheet page of the vba editor:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Chart_Calculate()

ChartObjects("grafiek 4").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Width = 637.783
ActiveChart.Legend.Left = 716.514
ActiveChart.Legend.Width = 176.735
ActiveChart.Legend.Height = 295.334

End Sub
```

having this code, I assumed the automatic resizing would be gone, but I saw the legend sometimes still overlaps te plot area.

Is there a solution which permanently fixes this problem?

**Edit1:**

Yesterday, I simply added a few parameters for the plot area. It seemed to work then. But now I tried again, and the legend is overlapping the plot area again.

I changed the code to:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Chart_Calculate()

ChartObjects("grafiek 4").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Top = 33.102
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Left = 67.1
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Width = 637.783
ActiveChart.Legend.Top = 7
ActiveChart.Legend.Left = 716.514
ActiveChart.Legend.Width = 176.735
ActiveChart.Legend.Height = 329.667

End Sub
```

So with 2 more paramters for the plot area.

**edit2:** 
I have checked the legend properties in Excel. under 'options for legend' there is a checkbox: show legend without overlapping plot area (I do not know the exact english text).
This box is checked, but it does overlap the plot area.

Why is it impossible to achieve this? Having fixed sizes for the plot area and the legend should not be so hard.

**edit 3:** 
I do have this routine now in my workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Chart_Calculate()

ChartObjects("grafiek 4").Activate
With ActiveChart
    With .PlotArea
        .Top = 33.102
        .Left = 67.1
        .Width = 637.783
    End With
    With .Legend
        .IncludeInLayout = True
        .Position = xlLegendPositionRight
        .AutoScaleFont = False
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Top = 5
        .Left = 706.899
        .Width = 179.735
        .Height = 336.681
    End With
End With

End Sub
Sub kopieergrafiek()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Grafiek 4").Copy

End Sub
```

(including the suggestion in the comment below my post)

I does not seem to work. Does worksheet_change event perhaps works better?

**edit 4:** 
I still do not have a solution for this issue. It already happens when the name of 1 of the legend items is to long to fit the space. And it also happens when there are to many items in the legend to fit in the space available.

I think there is no solution for this. Unless I could somehow tell excel to maximize the number of items in the legend. or to maximize the length of the series name.

Comment: May not be exactly what you want but you can separate the legend from the plot area like this: `ActiveChart.Legend.IncludeInLayout = True` and then set the position like this: `ActiveChart.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionRight`

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem myself with the legend resizing the plot area. I tried what Portland Runner suggested, only setting .Legend.IncludeInLayout to false (thus separating the legend from the plot area as he suggested, perhaps he made a typo?) and my plot area was no longer resized.

Comment: I was working with this template again when I thought about adding a column where shorter items names are created. Those shorters names could then be used for the chart / series. 

Thinking one step further about this, I thought that it might be possible to use formulas for the series names i.e. : left(cell, 30) limiting the series name to the first 30 characters of the item name. Then the series names will never be longer then 30 and this will make the legend not resize anymore. I do not know if this is possible by VBA.

Comment: I simply changed my vba code. I have added a new variabel which now is used in my pivot to display sku's but now with a shorter name. All the items for this variabel now have name which is no longer then 60 characters. This was the easiest thing for me to do to get the result that I want. The code simply uses =left( RC, 60) to create the shorter name and after that, all formulas are stored as values with *range().value = range().value*

Comment: strange - I also ran Portlands two lines of code against each chart and they are now behaving i.e. the legends are not overlapping the charts when the number of entries in the legend changes

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but since I had the same issue and was able to solve it, but did not really find the correct answer on this thread, I thought it would be good to post my solution. It is really important to refresh the pivotlayout, otherwise you will not see a difference in the Chart Legend. This will adjust the Legend so it will not overlap the plot area. It will also increase the size of the chart, so if you do not want that, you will need to use other code.

```
 Sub AdjustChartLegendActiveSheet()
Dim j
    For j = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.count
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes(j).Type = msoChart Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(j).chart.Legend.IncludeInLayout = True
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(j).chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotCache.Refresh
        End If
    Next j
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and found this answer. I found a fix that works for me. Not sure why exactly it works but I do these steps:

- Set the legend position
- Undock the legend (legend.includeLayout = false)
- Resize the plot area to the size I wanted
- Re-dock the Legend (legend.includeLayout = True)
- Set the Legend.Left position
  and after that the legend is correctly positioned and lined up.